# Participation vs Participations

Tags: singular-vs-plural

This is the way I initially phrased my sentence:

> *Some of his most important achievements **are** his **participations** in the annual singing contest and the Nottingham cooking contest.*

My confusion mostly stems from the fact that I found a [source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/is-participation-countable-or-uncountable.2937856/) saying that the noun 'participation' is uncountable in most cases. Additionally, *Grammarly* suggests that I simply replace *participations* with *participation*:

> *Some of his most important achievements **are** his **participation** in the annual singing contest and the Nottingham cooking contest.*

But shouldn't I change *are* to *is* then? Even if I do that, the sentence still doesn't make much sense to me:

> *Some of his most important achievements **is** his **participation** in the annual singing contest and the Nottingham cooking contest.*

Which of these is grammatically correct?

Comment: No - it's completely unidiomatic to pluralise ***participation*** in such contexts, even if the referent participates in multiple activities. Exactly the same logic applies to, for example, *His **enjoyment** of classical music and playing squash make him unusual among his peer group*, where you'd never see plural ***enjoyments***.

Comment: participation here is an abstract or mass noun.

Comment: ***achievements*** here is a countable noun, which is why it's ***are***, not ***is***.

Comment: So the sentence *Some of his most important achievements are his participation in the annual singing contest and in the Nottingham cooking contest* is correct?                     I guess what makes it confusing for me is that the plural noun **achievements** is followed by the singular noun **participation**.